# adding an option of your application to window's right click menu

Tags: java, windows

i am creating a java application and want to provide a functionality of it in mouse right click menu on windows os 
like if we have notepad++ installed then if we right click on some file then it shows an option "edit with notepad++"
i want to do similar kind of thing but with selected text

Comment: Please clarify your question: Do you want your program to appear in the right-click menu of *other* programs in Windows when text is selected, or do you want to have a right-click menu in your own program?

Comment: i want one of my program's functionality to appear on right click not just in my application but anywhere suppose i select some text in ms wordpad then  right click on it then my program functionality should appear there  as cut,copy,paste etc does appear

Comment: That's still not clear. Appear on right click **where**?

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to add to your program a functionality to insert your program path into the registry. Check [adding program to windows right click option menu](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-any-application-to-the-desktop-right-click-menu-in-vista/) for help.

Comment: I think OP means he wants to add right-click functionality *inside* his application ("with selected text").

Comment: no 
 
i want one of my program's functionality to appear on right click not just in my application but anywhere suppose i select some text in ms wordpad then right click on it then my program functionality should appear there as cut,copy,paste etc does appear

Comment: Yep, my ans covers it, but you have to look for the specific path in the registry to add your app location and associate it with text....